# What method body do I need for a compareTo() method that tests if the strings held by 2 objects are equal?

Tags: java, object, testing, junit

The test should compare the values held by the objects and then return 0 if they are equal. The objects are Person objects and they contain a first and last name. I already have a toString() method as shown below that might be used.

My main problem is what I need to pass to the method. Is it an (Object o) or (Person p).

Then inside the method I can't work out how to distinguish between the two objects if I am only passing one to it?

Here's some code:

```
//In the PersonTest class
/**
 * Test compareTo method, of class Person
 */
@Test
public void testCompareTo()
{
    System.out.println("compareTo");

    Person p2 = new Person("John", "Smiths");
    Person p3 = new Person("NotJohn", "Smiths");

    int actual = p1.compareTo(p2);
    int expected = 0;  
    assertEquals(expected, actual);

    actual = p1.compareTo(p3);
    expected = -1;
    assertNotSame(expected, actual);


}
//in the Person class

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}


public int compareTo(Person p)
{
    if (toString().equals(p.toString())) //Are they equal
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (toString() < p.toString())//Is one smaller
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else //Is one bigger
    {
        return 1;
    }   

}
```

Comment: You need more/better tests - how about checking that two unequal objects come out unequal? And shouldn't the result of `compareTo` be different if the first object is less than the second than if it is greater than?

Comment: Yes Alan, I'm implementing that now. I am going to test all three scenarios and am adding code for to the method now. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: `equals()` returns a boolean. What you need is something that returns a positive value, 0 or a negative value, and doesn't break the compareTo contract. You should thus delegate to `String.compareTo()`, and not to `String.equals()`. Returning -1 every time two items aren't equal would lead to a < b and b < a at the same time, which is invalid.

Comment: How do I compare the strings so that I can know which one is bigger? I can't use the edited code above because < isn't valid with strings?

Comment: By delegating to String.compareTo(), as I explained: `return toString().compareTo(p.toString());` That's all you need in your compareTo method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have it working now and have added tests for all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a method, `this` refers to the current object.

So you could write

```
if (this.toString().equals(p.toString()))
```

This works particularly well if you rename `p` to `that`.

Even more concisely

```
if (toString().equals(p.toString()))
```

(The first call to `toString()` is implicitly on the current object.)